# How to execute DL - RNN model on text in golang?

Tags: go, tensorflow, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

I have build `RNN` model in `tensor-flow` based on reddit/twitter conversations. I saved it in `pb`. Does anyone know how to pass raw text string through the model in `golang` and produce output?

```
modeldir := "/my_model.pb"

// Buffer input text
var buffer bytes.Buffer

args := os.Args[1:]

for _, arg := range args {
    buffer.WriteString(arg + " ")
}

inputText := buffer.String()

// Load the serialized GraphDef from a file.

model, err := ioutil.ReadFile(modeldir)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// Construct an in-memory graph from the serialized form.
graph := tf.NewGraph()
if err := graph.Import(model, ""); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// Create a session for inference over graph.
session, err := tf.NewSession(graph, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer session.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tfgo](https://github.com/galeone/tfgo) to easily load into Go and use a trained tensorflow model: just export the trained model using `tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder` as shown in the `tfgo` README.

However, you just have to extract from the graph the input placeholder and then feed the network using it.

Let's suppose you exported your model calling it `my_model` and tagged it with the tag `tag`. Also let's suppose that your input placeholder is named "Placeholder". Moreover, you have to know the name of your output node. Let's call it `output/node/path/op`. Then your code should look like:

```
import (
        "fmt"
        tg "github.com/galeone/tfgo"
        tf "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go"
        "flags"
)

func main() {
        model := tg.LoadModel("my_model", []string{"tag"}, nil)

        // Buffer input text
        var buffer bytes.Buffer
        args := os.Args[1:]

        for _, arg := range args {
            buffer.WriteString(arg + " ")
        }
        // handle the retunred error below, if any
        inputText, _ := tf.NewTensor(buffer.String())

        results := model.Exec([]tf.Output{
                model.Op("output/node/path/op", 0),
        }, map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
                model.Op("Placeholder", 0): inputText,
        })
        // do something with results[0]
}
```

Comment: how would you use `tg.Cast` function to convert inputText to `tensorflow` type ?. Do i need to crate root first as `root := tg.NewRoot()` and then `A = tg.Cast(root, A, tf.Int32)` ? Function info specifies: `Cast casts the current tensor to the requested dtype`. Could you explain how to convert to `inputText` to current tensor ? and what is `root` role in the conversion?

Comment: The root is the root of your graph. Is required because you're describing a graph. However, if you want to convert `inputText` (Go variable) to a tensor (thus to a `tf.Output` variable that holds your `inputText`), you don't have to use `tg.Cast` (that works among tensors), but you have to use `tg.Const` in order to create a `tf.Output` from a Go value

Comment: thx for that, but I think this is incorrect as `inputText := buffer.String()` and
`inputTextTensor := tg.Const(root, inputText)` does not match type signature of ` `results := model.Exec([]tf.Output{
model.Op("output/node/path/op", 0),
 }, map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
  model.Op("input_data", 0): inputTextTensor,
 })`  with error: `cannot use inputTextTensor (type tensorflow.Output) as type *tensorflow.Tensor in map value`

Comment: My bad, sorry. If you are going to feed the graph you don't have to define a node in the graph (that's what `tg.Const` does) but you have to create a pointer to a `tf.Tensor` using  NewTensor: https://godoc.org/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go#NewTensor